# Eulerian polynomial problem - Signed permutations

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

Assume that $B_{n,k}$ is the number of signed permutations with size n which have exactly $k$ descents.
$$B_n(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}t^k,$$

$$\frac{B_n(t)}{(1-t)^{n+1}}=\sum_{k\geq0} (2k+1)^nt^k,$$ and
that the recurence relation

$$B_{n+1,k}=(2k+1)B_{n,k} + (2n-2k+3)B_{n,k-1}$$ is valid.

I want to show that $$\frac{B_{n+1}(1)}{B_n(1)}=2n+2.$$

$\textbf{Problem:}$ How do I get a non-recursive relation out of $$B_{n+1,k}=(2k+1)B_{n,k} + (2n-2k+3)B_{n,k-1}?$$

---

For a better understanding of the recursion, I decided to show what the first cases in the recursion are.

Let's start with $B_{1,0}$ and $B_{1,1}$ (so we are looking at $\{-1,0,1\}$). Here it is also important that we only consider one side of the zero for counting descents!
That means, that for $\{-2,1,0,-1,2\}$ we would only consider descents starting at 0 that is there only one descent in this case, that being $(0,-1)$
$$B_{1,0}=1$$ since  only $\{-1,0,1\}$ contains no descents;
$$B_{1,1}=1$$ since only $\{1,0,-1\}$ contains 1 descent

Now let's proceed to the second case, $B_{2,k}$

$$B_{2,0}=(2*0+1)B_{1,0}+0=1$$
This makes sense since the only way to get no descents for $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ would be the identity permutation.
$$B_{2,1}=6$$
these permutations are $\{2,-1,0,1,-2\}$, $\{-2,1,0,-1,2\}$, $\{-1,-2,0,2,1\}$, $\{-1,2,0,-2,1\}$, $\{1,-2,0,2,-1\}$ and $\{1,2,0,-2,-1\}$.

Finally, $$B_{2,2}=1$$
As there is only 1 permutation with 2 descents, that being $\{2,1,0,-1,-2\}$

Comment: Are you going to define $B_{n=0,k=0}$? Every recurrence needs an initial condition to be meaningfully solved

Comment: By descent do you mean: $0,3,2,5,4,1$ would be a permutation of $6$ elements with $3$ descents?

Comment: Yes. The descents "pairs" would be (3,2), (5,4) and (4,1)

Comment: I did some further alterations to make the question and the counting of $B_{n,k}$ more understandable, by calculating the values of $B_{n,k}$ for $n=1,2$

Comment: Hint:  Use linearity of expectation on the triples $\{0, a, b\}$ to see which ones result in descents $(a, b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak{B_n}$ be the type B Coxeter group.

You intend to show that $\frac{B_{n+1}(1)}{B_n(1)}=2n+2$.

We just have to see what $B_n(1)$ is. $$B_n(t)=\sum\limits _{w\in\mathfrak{B_n}}t^{des_B(w)}.$$

Now, setting $t=1$ gives, $$B_n(1)= \sum\limits_{w\in\mathfrak{B_n}} 1=|\mathfrak{B_n}|.$$

Therefore, the identity we wish to proof is $$|\mathfrak{B}_{n+1}|=(2n+2)|\mathfrak{B}_n|.$$

This is apparent as we can insert either $n+1$ or $\overline{n+1}$ into any one of the $n+1$ positions in a signed permutation of $\mathfrak{B}_n$.

---

I found this question while looking for something else and thought I'd remove it from the 'unanswered' list.